# pymongo convert mongoDB date to python datetime

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, datetime, pymongo, bson

I have a MongoDB database which has some time entries (eg. creation dates of some entities). When I look at them in the database, they seem to be in a 64-bit integer BSON format. The database entry was originally created using C# (ASP.NET Core) using the following representation:

```
[BsonRepresentation(MongoDB.Bson.BsonType.Decimal128)]
```

I want to access that database using a Python script to get some stats. I can get that entry in my python code using `pymongo`. A typical value looks like this: `[637013892303590646, 0]`. How can I convert it into a python `datetime` value that is human readable?

If I print the variable type which I get from pymongo, it says: `bson.int64.Int64`

I looked at the `bson` module documentation here: https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/bson/index.html, but I couldn't find a suitable function to do the conversion. Can someone please point me the right call to convert the `bson.int64.Int64` to a `datetime` value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is in [ticks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.ticks?view=netframework-4.8); defined as:

> The value of this property represents the number of 100-nanosecond
>   intervals that have elapsed since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001
>   in the Gregorian calendar, which represents MinValue. It does not
>   include the number of ticks that are attributable to leap seconds. If
>   the DateTime object has its Kind property set to Local, its ticks
>   represent the time elapsed time since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1,
>   0001 in the local time as specified by the current time zone setting.
>   If the DateTime object has its Kind property set to Utc, its ticks
>   represent the time elapsed time since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1,
>   0001 in the Coordinated Universal Time. If the DateTime object has its
>   Kind property set to Unspecified, its ticks represent the time elapsed
>   time since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001 in the unknown time
>   zone.

so we can write a `ticks_to_datetime()` function which uses a timedelta based on midnight Jan 1 0001, dividing by 10 to convert from 100-nanoseconds to microseconds.

```
import pymongo
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from bson import Int64

def ticks_to_datetime(ticks):
    return datetime(1, 1, 1) + timedelta(microseconds=ticks / 10)

mydb = pymongo.MongoClient()['mydatabase']

mydb.mycollection.insert_one({'old_time': [Int64(637013892303590646), 0]})
record = mydb.mycollection.find_one({})
old_time = record['old_time'][0]
new_time = ticks_to_datetime(old_time)
print(new_time)
```

gives:

```
2019-08-14 14:20:30.359062
```